# How to create a route to an anchor on a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, link-to, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Rails 4.2. I have a single page website, index.html.erb, Controller: Visitors. The navigation links are "About", "Services", "Pricing", etc. The navigation links are as follows:

<%= link_to "About", anchor: "section2" %>

<%= link_to "Services", anchor: "section3" %>

<%= link_to "Pricing", anchor: "section4" %>

As is each link works but the url looks like this
    http://domain.com/#section2

I want the url to look as follows, I want the matched word "About" to point to the selected anchor
    http://domain.com/about

I tried a few of these variations in routes.rb but nothing worked.
    match 'about', to: 'visitors#index', anchor: "section2", via: :get

I also tried to do a redirect in the visitors controller, about action as follows
    redirect_to action: "index", anchor: "section2"

Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

considering `about` is an actual route, your `link_to` should look like this:

```
link_to 'about', about_path(anchor: 'section2')
```

This will create: `http://domain.com/about#section2`

Key here, is to pass the anchor as a parameter to your `foo_path(anchor: '..', ...)`

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly you expect some magic which will make `http://domain.com/about` point to `http://domain.com/#about`.

Good news, this is possible :)

Write in your `routes.rb` following line:

```
get '/about', to: redirect('/#about')
```